# Is Jesus implying that He expects his disciples to be Sabbath-keepers in Matthew 24:20?

Tags: matthew, jesus, law, sabbath, ten-commandments

In Matthew 24:15-25 (NIV) we read:

> 15 “So when you see standing in the holy place ‘the abomination that causes desolation,’ spoken of through the prophet Daniel—let the reader understand— 16 then let those who are in Judea flee to the mountains. 17 Let no one on the housetop go down to take anything out of the house. 18 Let no one in the field go back to get their cloak. 19 How dreadful it will be in those days for pregnant women and nursing mothers! 20 **Pray that your flight will not take place in winter or on the Sabbath**. 21 For then there will be great distress, unequaled from the beginning of the world until now—and never to be equaled again.
> 22 “If those days had not been cut short, no one would survive, but for the sake of the elect those days will be shortened. 23 At that time if anyone says to you, ‘Look, here is the Messiah!’ or, ‘There he is!’ do not believe it. 24 For false messiahs and false prophets will appear and perform great signs and wonders to deceive, if possible, even the elect. 25 See, I have told you ahead of time.

Is Jesus encouraging his disciples to pray that "your flight will not take place in the winter or **on the Sabbath**" because He implicitly expects them to be Sabbath-keepers according to the 4th commandment? If so, is this an expectation that applies to Jewish disciples only or both Jewish and Gentile disciples?

Comment: I do not believe we will get anywhere with this question.  Commentators are sharply divided precisely along which day they believe we should keep.  Both will not countenance any debate from the other side and both jump to conclusions.  worse, if one were to post that was truly fair, it would be derided by one side or the other.  The Christian community is not yet mature enough to even debate this topic.

Comment: @Dottard, the question does not seem to have anything to do with "which day", the question is about whether the disciples are expected to keep it.

Comment: @Dottard The matter of the sabbath (as the matter of circumcision) is an important one. Paul deals with it and stresses the importance of a right understanding regarding Old Covenant and New Testament, regarding legal works and justifying faith, regarding the Law of Moses and the Gospel of Jesus Christ. Whether some wish to debate the matter or not, the fact is that James exhorts to 'earnestly contend for the faith' and this contention is in contradiction to those who support a way of legal works, legal sabbath-keeping and legal circumcision.

Comment: We are warned by Jesus that fleeing from a place within a Jewish controlled region on the Sabbath  would cause problems, because public transport would not operate, service stations would be closed, and cars on the roads would meet with suspicion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The context of the scriptures is very key.  Matt. chap. 24 & 25 is a discussion centered around the destruction of the temple in Jerusalem.

> *"And having gone forth, Jesus departed from the temple, and his disciples came near to show him the buildings of the temple,*

> *2 and Jesus said to them, `Do ye not see all these? verily I say to you, There may not be left here a stone upon a stone, that shall not be thrown down.'*

> *3 And when he is sitting on the mount of the Olives, the disciples came near to him by himself, saying, `Tell us, when shall these be? and what [is] the sign of thy presence, and of the **full end of the age**?'"*  (Matt. 24:1-3, YLT)

His disciples remembered the previous time the temple had been destroyed, the reason for that destruction being the evil sins of the people of Judah, and their banishment to Babylon for seventy years.  They knew that Christ was telling them about another day of judgment that was to come upon their generation if that temple was going to be destroyed again.

So, Christ was answering the question His disciples had asked - "when".  When was the temple going to be destroyed. Both chapters of Matt 24 and 25 were warnings to watch for the time of the destruction of the temple.  In vs. 15-17 He tells them to flee to the mountains when they see certain things, not to go back and get anything from their houses, but to just go.

Since they were to flee to the mountains, it was going to be a long journey.  That flight would be more difficult if it was during the cold winter months.  Or, if it was on a Sabbath day, which included the feast days as those were also Sabbath days, then they would be caught unaware either during a day of keeping in their homes or in the temple or synagogues where they would not be watching outside.

The parallel in Luke chap. 21 gives more detail on this warning.

> *"20 `And when ye may see Jerusalem **surrounded by encampments**, then know that come nigh did her desolation;*

> *21 then those in Judea, let them flee to the mountains; and those in her midst, let them depart out; and those in the countries, let them not come in to her;*

> *22 because these are days of vengeance, to fulfil all things that have been written.*

> *23 `And wo to those with child, and to those giving suck, in those days; for there shall be great distress on the land, and wrath on this people;*

> *24 **and they shall fall by the mouth of the sword**, and shall be led captive to all the nations, and Jerusalem shall be trodden down by nations, till the times of nations be fulfilled."*  (Luke 21:20-24, YLT)

Christ was not warning them about the end-of-the-world, nor the end of time.  The encampments and falling under the sword was a battle scenario with armies surrounding Jerusalem.  This happened when the Romans attacked Jerusalem during the Roman-Jewish wars of AD 67-70.  The destruction of their temple was the "end of the age" about which the disciples had asked.  It was the end of the Mosaic animal sacrificial age.

They were keeping the Sabbaths, and all of the temple laws until that temple was destroyed.  And, that day of the Lord, that coming of the Lord in judgment against those who had crucified Him and were persecuting His saints was the judgment promised to come upon that generation.

> *"Verily I say to you, **this generation** may not pass away till all these may come to pass."*  (Matt. 24:34, YLT)

It is not "this" generation when we are reading it today.  It was their generation, the generation which existed when Christ spoke the words.

The instructions were for them, and the situation does not apply to us today.  We cannot lift the scriptures out of their time and place.  We don't read the OT and the instructions God gave to Noah and think that we are supposed to build an ark today.  The same hermeneutic applies, that the scriptures must be read with the first audience perspective.

More detail about the first audience perspective is available at my blog ShreddingTheVeil.org.  Recommend the post "Perspective" at the top menu [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/perspective/), and then begin reading the other posts.

Comment: Well said, sound perspective.

Answer (score 4):

When we interpret such things, first of all, a precise philosophical-theological principle should be established, otherwise we are doomed to commit an error.

Here we should establish as the principle the great philosophical-theological insight which Jesus gave to His disciples of all epochs and generations: "Sabbath is for man, not man for Sabbath" (Mark 2:27), that is to say, all rituals and observances should be taken mindfully, in Holy Spirit, and not slavishly, turning such rituals and observances into an idol strangling human freedom and divine dignity. Thus, when hungry, the disciples can reap wheat on a field and eat even in Sabbath (Matthew 12:1); when man is ill, a doctor can heal him and even must heal him even in Sabbath (cf. Matthew 12:13).

If so, will it not be absurd to consider that Jesus commands His followers that if perchance the siege of Jerusalem happens on Sabbath, they will be doomed to be massacred by Romans, because it is unlawful for them to flee in Sabbath according to Law? Yes, it will be beyond stupidity, because the only thing Jesus would have told them would be: "flee! save yourselves and your children!", because if He cannot suffer His disciples' health to be endangered by hunger and permits them to reap wheat on Sabbath, how can He suffer them not to flee when their very life is endangered by Roman legionaries?!

Thus, since this is excluded, any other interpretation that will not run into such gross mistake will be welcome.

Another issue is that ancient Christian Church of the first centuries in Roman Empire shifted the weight of the sanctity on Sunday, the day of Lord's Resurrection which they put above the Sabbath. Yet, be it Sunday or be it Sabbath, or be it any other day of the week, still, Jesus would have said to endangered people: "Any Feast Day, Sabbath or Sunday, is for you, not you for the Feast Day! So, do not endanger your lives by a slavish and unmindful observance of Feast, for this is not according to Me and the Holy Spirit, you will not please, thus, Father by this! So, flee and rescue yourselves and your children!"

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe Jesus is implying that He expects His disciples to be Sabbath keepers and certainly not from Matthew 24:20.

Let me set the table with some context. At Matthew 24:3 the disciples ask Jesus a very important question? "And as He was sitting on the Mount of Olives, the disciples came to Him privately, saying, "Tell us when will these things be, and what will be the sign of Your coming, AND THE END OF THE AGE."

Jesus answered both questions, but not in order. Also He did not answer these questions according to a chronological sequence, but topically. Jesus was more concerned about "BEING READY FOR HIS COMING" than exactly when it would occur. Jesus was also warning about deception.

Matthew 24:15, "Therefore when you see the Abomination of desolation which was spoken of through Daniel the prophet, standing in the holy place, (let the reader understand).

Jesus then speaks about instant flight from Judea. He outlines situations that people will be in that will make it hard for them to escape. At Matthew 24:20, Jesus is saying, (and I'm paraphrasing), Pray/hope that your flight may not be in winter, or on the Sabbath;"

The implication being that the winter which includes ice and snow, would slow them down. Now, what is the significance of the Sabbath day? I had to look this up and the following is from Barns notes.

"Neither on the sabbath-day - Long journeys were prohibited by the law on the Sabbath, Exodus 16:29. The law of Moses did not mention the distance to which persons might go on the Sabbath, but most of the Jews maintained that it should not be more than 2000 cubits. Some supposed that it was 7 furlongs, or nearly a mile. This distance was allowed in order that they might go to their places of worship. Most of them held that it was not lawful to go further, under any circumstances of war or affliction. Jesus teaches his disciples to pray that their flight might not be on the Sabbath, because, if they should not go farther than a Sabbath-day's journey, they would not be beyond the reach of danger, and if they did, they would be exposed to the charge of violating the law. It should be added that it was almost impracticable to travel in Judea on that day, as the gates of the cities were usually closed, Nehemiah 13:19-22."

So in summary, I do not believe from the context that the issue has to do with the disciples keeping the Sabbath day.

Comment: The fact that Jesus is telling his disciples to pray that their flight be not on the Sabbath day at the destruction of Jerusalem which was much latter after his death tells us in the scripture itself that Jesus was expecting his disciples to be continuing to keep the Sabbath. If not he would not be giving the warning to pray their escape was not on the Sabbath day.

Comment: @3rdAngel The context is not about the disciples keeping the Sabbath. They ask Jesus, vs3, "What is the sign of your coming AND THE END OF THE WORLD." I happen to be a post-tribulationist and Matthew 24 is about the great tribulation. The "tip off" is at verse 15. "Therefore  when you see the antichrist let the reader understand." Get out of Dodge. Jesus describes and says let's hope your not with child, hope your flight is not in the winter time or on the Sabbath. Look out for false Christ and deception etc. After the tribulation (vs29) what happens 3rdAngel? Verses 29-31. Jesus returns! Amen

Answer (score 3):

**Overview**
It is often noted Jesus in some form repeated nine of the Ten Commandments; omitting the one to keep the Sabbath. Thus one may reason: by failing to state the necessity, continuing to keep the Sabbath is no longer a requirement. I find this line of reasoning overly simplistic, if not naïve. For example, if Jesus had failed to restate the commands not to kill, or steal, or bear false witness, or commit adultery, would these behaviors now be understood as no longer prohibited? Does any Christian really believe "liberty" from the Law means behavior is no longer subject to the Law?

Jesus required those who believe to be followers. Jesus observed the Sabbath and logically His followers should do likewise; not according to manmade rules, by according to Scripture. Jesus specifically addresses this issue in John:

> <sup>19</sup> Has not Moses given you the law? Yet none of you keeps the law. Why do you seek to kill me?” <sup>20</sup> The crowd answered, “You have a demon! Who is seeking to kill you?” <sup>21</sup> Jesus answered them, “I did one work, and you all marvel at it. <sup>22</sup> Moses gave you circumcision (not that it is from Moses, but from the fathers), and you circumcise a man on the Sabbath. <sup>23</sup> If on the Sabbath a man receives circumcision, so that the law of Moses may not be broken, are you angry with me because on the Sabbath I made a man's whole body well? <sup>24</sup> Do not judge by appearances, but judge with right judgment.” (John 7) [ESV]

If one is commanded to follow, it is unnecessary to restate a previous positive instruction. Hence the overly simplistic argument of making significant Jesus' failure to restate the command. If there is an issue, it is Jesus' failure to completely recast the command in the negative: do not stop keeping the Sabbath.

For followers it is necessary to remember, restating **prohibited** behavior is different from restating **required** behavior. For example, since Jesus did not marry on earth, the command not to commit adultery **must** be restated. This type of restatement is not a law; it is required because Jesus cannot provide His followers with the positive example of His own actions. So restating any prohibition is simply an affirmation to **continue** to follow Jesus' example.

Keeping the Sabbath is something followers should do because that is what Jesus did, and the issue is **how**, not **if** Jesus kept the Sabbath.

**Matthew 24:20**
The passage needs to be considered in context:

> <sup>15</sup> “So when you see the abomination of desolation spoken of by the prophet Daniel, standing in the holy place (let the reader understand), <sup>16</sup> then let those who are in Judea flee to the mountains. <sup>17</sup> Let the one who is on the housetop not go down to take what is in his house, <sup>18</sup> and let the one who is in the field not turn back to take his cloak. <sup>19</sup> And alas for women who are pregnant and for those who are nursing infants in those days! 20 Pray that your flight may not be in winter or on a Sabbath. (Matthew 24)

Jesus commands a certain group to take a certain action:

> ...then let those who are in Judea flee to the mountains...pray that your flight may not be in winter or on a Sabbath.

Whether Christians should observe the Sabbath is a good question, but this particular passage cannot be taken as anything more than instruction for those who are in Judea to flee to the mountains. That is to say, just as no one sees this as a call for all people to go to the mountains; this should be approached as instruction to take flight for those specifically in Judea.

First, Jesus linked winter and the Sabbath. Obviously man has no control over "observing" winter. Then to pray the flight does not occur in winter is simply a practical consideration:

> ...let those who are in Judea flee to the mountains...pray that your flight may not be in winter...

Not only is travel in winter more difficult, fleeing to the mountains (the positive command) makes the destination even more extreme. The proper interpretation is to pray the required travel will not occur during a season in which travel is the most difficult and the destination will be the most inhospitable.

The Sabbath is marked by human activity or inactivity. In Judea, or any place with a large Jewish population, the Sabbath will be identified by a cessation of normal work and commerce. A trip which must be made quickly will be more problematic on a Sabbath. Not as a result of breaking a prohibition on how far one may travel on the Sabbath (something not specifically addressed in the Law); rather, it recognizes a trip on the Sabbath will be more difficult because food and clothing for the journey will be difficult, or even impossible to obtain:

> then let those who are in Judea flee to the mountains. Let the one who is on the housetop not go down to take what is in his house, and let the one who is in the field not turn back to take his cloak...pray that your flight may not be in winter or on a Sabbath

The one at home is not to go inside to prepare for a journey. Arguably, in winter they would be wearing a coat, but not have food ready for a trip. On the other hand, one in the field would likely not be in the winter and not wearing a coat (which would be needed upon arriving in the mountains).

**Summary**
In Matthew 24 Jesus is addressing the practical reality of those in Judea "dropping everything" and fleeing to the mountains for safety. In Judea, businesses will be closed on the Sabbath. A trip in winter or when food and clothing cannot be purchased along the way will be more difficult.

Therefore it is reasonable to conclude Jesus expects the Sabbath will be observed in Judea and that would make unplanned travel on a Sabbath more difficult. However, those making the journey will not be violating the Sabbath: they will following the instructions of Jesus.

Since this particular instruction is specific to hastened travel in Judea to the mountains, it neither adds nor subtracts from Jesus' expectations for His followers to observe the Sabbath.

Comment: Two comments: 1) The argument "If Jesus did it, we have to do it" can also be applied to circumcision (Jesus was circumcised). Should we get circumcised too? Likewise, Jesus performed lots of miracles, raised the dead, cast out demons, fasted for 40 days. Should the disciples do the same today? 2) This answer could be improved by addressing my OP's last question: are Gentile disciples included in the expectation? Based on your answer, it looks like Sabbath observance is expected to happen in Judea, a Jewish location, but what can we infer anything for the Gentiles?

Comment: Should also add Colossians 2:16 which specifically says we treat all days the same. The bottom line is that the Sabbath was a type for Christ. Christ is our rest now; we rest in him all the time.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator 1) Jesus did not circumcise Himself; His parents acted on His behalf. In addition, the issue of Gentile circumcision is plainly addressed in the NT; this believers are guided by the NT on that issue. 2) The passage clearly states "*then let those who are in Judea flee to the mountains.*" There is nothing to support a universal extension much less an universal application to either Gentiles or Jewish people living outside of Judea. I don't think you have a question about whether Gentiles who are not living in Judea should flee to the mountains of Judea.

Comment: @LanceRoberts The question of whether the Sabbath should be observed and how and on what day of the week are all valid, but none of them can be construed from the passage in this question which simply speaks to those in Judea fleeing to the mountains.

Answer (score 2):

I put this out for consideration.

Having been a Sabbath KEEPER for decades (but no longer), While this passage has immediate implications for the hearers of Jesus (as others have pointed out) there is some aspect that may apply to others today as Jesus' disciples. Some who may still OBSERVE (1) a Sabbath and cherish the opportunity for time with God and family - brothers and sisters in Christ and to spend time allocated with children to teach as we are admonished.

> Deuteronomy 11:19  You shall teach them to your sons, talking of them when you sit in your house and when you walk along the road and when you lie down and when you rise up.

There is no 'command' to keep a Sabbath under the New Covenant, but that does not diminish the opportunity to partake of the benefits long held dear.

1. by observe I mean to set the day aside for generally Godly purposes and pursuits, but not to adhere to the sunset to sunset, or many other limitations imposed on the 'holy time that was required under the law.

Regarding any *requirement* to 'keep' a Sabbath today, we can look to Jesus as a guide.

1. He did things on the Sabbath that were contrary to traditional understanding and practises
2. We are never told he rested on the Sabbath
3. the Sabbath was one of many signs that separated Israel from the Gentile nations - this separation is now removed in Christ.
4. He spoke about the Sabbath wasn't intended to be a burden - the Sabbath was made for man, not the reverse Mark 2:27.
5. Like practically everything in the OT, they were a type of something far grander - Jesus came to point to this progression and initiate some of the changes. The Holy Days still outline the plan of God, some are behind us, serving as a remembrance - sobering and serious, while some still look firmly forward to the end of days and an unspeakable joy.
6. Paul warns to not judge on things including the Sabbath and other OT practises.
7. There are no gains in righteousness by keeping a Sabbath - our entire standing is in Jesus by grace - certainly not by keeping a day!

Comment: Jesus was Lord of the Sabbath and came to teach us that it is lawful to do good on the Sabbath *Matthew 12:1-12. Jesus did not break the Sabbath as doing so would be sin. If Jesus sinned he could not be our perfect sacrifice.

Comment: Obviously agreed - https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/22791/in-the-gospel-of-john-did-the-jews-disbelieve-or-misunderstand-the-lord-jesus-c/50761#50761

Answer (score 2):

Yes, He is expecting those to whom this passage would apply to be keeping Sabbath, but that does not necessarily include all his disciples.

> Wherefore the **children of Israel** shall keep the sabbath, to observe the sabbath throughout their generations, for a **perpetual covenant**. It is a sign between **me and the children of Israel for ever**: for in six days the LORD made heaven and earth, and on the seventh day he rested, and was refreshed. (Exo 31:16-17)

Jews (and therefore Jewish Christians) continued to observe all the perpetual covenants and expectations in the Law of Moses even after the death and resurrection of Christ:

> And when they heard it, they glorified the Lord, and said unto him, Thou seest, brother, how many thousands of Jews there are which believe; and they are all zealous of the law: And they are informed of thee, that **thou teachest all the Jews** which are among the Gentiles **to forsake Moses**, saying that they ought not to circumcise their children, neither to walk after the customs. What is it therefore? the multitude must needs come together: for they will hear that thou art come. Do therefore this that we say to thee: We have four men which have a vow on them; Them take, and purify thyself with them, and be at charges with them, that they may shave their heads: and **all may know that those things, whereof they were informed concerning thee, are nothing**; but that **thou thyself also walkest orderly, and keepest the law**. As **touching the Gentiles which believe**, we have written and concluded that **they observe no such thing**, save only that they keep themselves from things offered to idols, and from blood, and from strangled, and from fornication. Then Paul took the men, and the next day purifying himself with them entered into the temple, to signify the accomplishment of the days of purification, until that an offering should be offered for every one of them. (Act 21:20-26)

So regardless of whether or not the Sabbath Keeping should be included in what is expected of Gentiles, James testifies, that the Jewish Christians, including Paul, *keepest the law* because it is a **perpetual covenant forever**.

Who is Jesus addressing in Matthew 24? Obviously, all the saints that are alive at that time, but in verse 20 he is addressing those that are in Judea:

> Then let *them which be in Judaea* flee into the mountains: (Mat 24:16)

It is reasonable to assume they would be Jews, who observe a Jewish Sabbath in a Jewish State that observe Jewish customs. Hence it will be similar to a pregnant woman trying to flee to the mountains - difficult!

I personally think that we (Gentiles) should observe **a** Sabbath, because it is part of the ten commandments and not exclusive to the Jewish ceremonials laws, but I cannot use this address in Matthew 24:15-20 to prove that Jesus expects all his disciples to observe **the** Sabbath. It definitely does prove that Jesus expected Jews in Judea to still observe THE Sabbath until the end.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple - unless you try (need) to ‘word’ your answer in such a way as to preserve other held interpretations.

Now to the simplicity ...

(1) A preceding verse makes it very clear who the intended audience is ..

**MAT 24:16** *then let those who are in Judea flee to the mountains.*

That is, Judea, that is, Jews. That is, Jews who had already rejected their Messiah earlier in Matthew. Therefore they would still be practicing ‘jews’ in the latter times. Quite clear.

(2) This takes place pre-cross. That is, the Jews, Jesus, the disciples, were still under Law, Torah. And, Jesus a Rabbi, would have to uphold the Law. (Sabbath).

The Olivet discourse was not a ‘sermon’ for the church. It was a sermon/discourse for the Jews. The sabbath is firmly entrenched into the Jewish culture. This passage was clearly directed at them.

‘Them’ being the Jews.

Comment: This answer is odd - if the sermon on Matt 24 is NOT meant for Christians and only Jews, then why read it?  I think you have destroyed your case by claiming too much.

Comment: But, how could the ‘audience’ be ‘christians’? To be a ‘Christian’ believer requires being reborn, which requires Jesus’s death to ‘achieve’, which hadn’t happened yet. Secondly, I in no way implied that if a passage is not directed to ‘the church’ (christians), that we can’t learn from it, that we can’t take from it - that this account isn’t for us. I didn’t say that. The question was - who was the expectation directed to, and I answered that.

Comment: There were many Christians in Jerusalem before its destruction who all left - that even was AFTER Jesus' death and resurrection.  It was the CHRISTIANS who recalled this very prophecy and left Jerusalem but many Jews flooded in and myriads perished.

Comment: No argument with this.  But, this ‘warning’ in Mat 24 is specifically for jews pre-Tribulation. There won’t be any ‘christians’ then, but the Jews that are there at that time will remember what happened in 70CE (as outlined in Luke’s Olivet account.) - and flee! I appreciate we are slipping into eschatology - interpretations differ. I also appreciate not everyone is going accept my answer/view, but, like all the other answers, it’s provided for consideration.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the bible teaches YES and absolutely! JESUS is expecting his disciples to be continuing to keep the Sabbath after His death and resurrection and that is precisely why it was written.

After all we are talking about God’s 4th commandment here which is one of God’s 10 commandments that gives us the knowledge of what sin is when broken according to the new covenant scriptures in Romans 3:20. The purpose of God’s law (10 commandments) according to God’s Word in the new covenant is to give us the knowledge of good and evil; sin and righteousness *Romans 7:7; 1 John 3:4; James 2:10-11 and to lead us to Christ that we might be forgiven through faith *Galatians 3:22-25; Matthew 9:12-13.

If we follow the biblical historical records through from the life and death and resurrection of JESUS, to the lives of the Apostles and early disciples, all of them kept all of God’s 10 commandments including God’s 4th commandment as shown in the biblical records * Matthew 12:1-8; 10-12; 24:20; Mark 3:1-5; Luke 6:1-10; 13:14-16; 14:1-5; John 7:22-23; 9:14; Mark 1:21; Mark 6:2; Luke 4:16; 31; Luke 14:1; 23:56; John 2:6; Matthew 16:24; 1 Corinthians 11:1; Ephesians 5:1-21; Peter 2:20-22; Acts 13:14; 13:27; 13:44; 15:21; 16:13; 17:2; 18:4; Revelation 1:10.

Now we could add the historical records to this but you have only asked for the biblical but if you’re interested the historical records show that Gods’ people since the death of JESUS have kept God’s Sabbath unbroken from the days of JESUS to this very present day.

Finally, there is not one scripture in all the Bible that says God’s 4th commandment of the 10 commandments has been abolished and we are now commanded to keep Sunday as a Holy day. This is a man-made teaching and tradition that has led many away from God and his Word and is not biblical. JESUS warns us about following man made teachings and traditions that break the commandments of God in Matthew 15:3-9. I can keep on going here but will stop for now.

The problem today in regard to God’s 4th commandment Sabbath is that it has become such a man made tradition that it is entrenched in the Church as a whole even though there is no supporting scripture for this teaching. Even the scriptures many use to support Sunday worship deny Gods 4th commandment “seventh day Sabbath” are scriptures pulled from their context to make them say things they do not say. Happy to discuss these later.

Remember dear friend *Exodus 20:8-11, only God’s Word is true and we should believe and follow it according to the scriptures over the teachings and traditions of men that break the commandments of God *Romans 3:4; Act 5:29; Matthew 15:3-9.

PS. Don't let anyone tell you there is no command to keep the Sabbath in the new covenant when Jesus, Paul and all the disciples kept the Sabbath and Jesus expected his disciples to be still keeping it after his death and resurrection. Everyone of God's 10 commandments are repeated in the new covenant.

Hebrews 4:9. Therefore it remains for the people of God to keep the Sabbath.

Comment: +1 for the Sunday serve, -1 for misquoting Hebrews 4:9

Comment: There was no misquoting Hebrews 4:9                                                           Aramaic Bible in Plain English So then, it remains for the people of God to keep the Sabbath.

Comment: STRONGS LEXICON
So ἄρα (ara) Conjunction Strong's Greek 686: Then, therefore, since. Probably from airo; a particle denoting an inference more or less decisive. there remains ἀπολείπεται (apoleipetai) Verb - Present Indicative Middle or Passive - 3rd Person Singular Strong's Greek 620: From apo and leipo; to leave behind; by implication, to forsake. a Sabbath rest σαββατισμὸς

Comment: (sabbatismos) Noun - Nominative Masculine Singular Strong's Greek 4520: A keeping of the Sabbath, a Sabbath rest. From a derivative of sabbaton; a 'sabbatism', i.e. the repose of Christianity. for the τῷ (tō) Article - Dative Masculine Singular Strong's Greek 3588: The, the definite article. Including the feminine he, and the neuter to in all their inflections; the definite article; the. people λαῷ (laō)

Comment: STRONGS CONCORDENCE
sabbatismos: a sabbath rest Original Word: σαββατισμός, οῦ, ὁ Part of Speech: Noun, Masculine
Transliteration:sabbatismos Phonetic Spelling: (sab-bat-is-mos') Definition: a sabbath rest
Usage: a keeping of the Sabbath, a Sabbath rest.

Comment: The translation for "Keeping Sabbath" comes from the Greek word that is used in Hebrews 4:9, σαββατισμός, pronounced sabbatismos, which is a noun form that means Sabbath rest, Sabbath (keeping) observance (Arndt and Gingrich, A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament).

Comment: The Greek word, σαββατισμός sabbatismos, is a noun. The verb form of the word is σαββατίζω sabbatizo, which means to keep the Sabbath (Arndt and Gingrich, A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament).

Comment: The use of the verb σαββατίζω sabbatizo in Leviticus 23:32 in the Septuagint leaves no room to mistake its meaning. The Greek English Lexicon of the Septuagint defines σαββατίζω sabbatizo as to keep sabbath, to rest (Lust, Eynikel, Hauspie).

Comment: Hebrews 4, verse 9: “There remains therefore a SABBATH rest to the people of God.” In verses 1, 3, 4 and 8, the Greek word for “rest” is katapausin. It means “rest.” But in verse 9, the Greek word for “rest” is sabbatismos, which is a Hebrew word—Sabbat, which means “the Sabbath”—combined with a Greek suffix—ismos, which means “a keeping of” or “a doing of.” Put together, sabbatismo means “a keeping of the Sabbath.” When correctly translated, Hebrews 4:9 should read, “There remains therefore a keeping of the Sabbath to the people of God.”

Comment: Leviticus is not Hebrews - one is OT one is NT - totally different focus. sabbatismos is used once, so hardly a good example to make strict doctrine with. We'll see what remarks others have on this approach to the text. TY.

Comment: Colossians 2:16 is quite clear that we no longer consider any day including the Sabbath holy. Christ is our rest that the Sabbath was the type for, now we rest in Christ and treat all days the same.

Answer (score 1):

I**s Jesus implying that He expects his disciples to be Sabbath-keepers in Matthew 24:20?**

Jesus does not expect his disciples to observe the Sabbath after his death.  WHY?

Jesus was a Jew, born under the Law and observed the Sabbath, the Christian scriptures state that "Jesus is the **end of the Law.**"(Rom 10:4) and that Christians are released from the requirements of the Law. ( Rom 7:6)

Romans 10:4 NASB

> 4 For Christ is **the end of the law** for righteousness to everyone who
> believes.

Romans 7:6 NET

> 6 But now we have been **released from the law** because we have died[a]
> to what controlled us, so that we may serve in the new life of the
> Spirit and not under the old written code.

The Christian scriptures state that Jesus's sacrifice ended the Law with its commands and regulations.

Ephesians 2:13-15 NIV

> 13 But now in Christ Jesus you who once were far away have been
> brought near by the blood of Christ. 14 For he himself is our peace,
> who has made the two groups one and has destroyed the barrier, the
> dividing wall of hostility, 15 **by setting aside in his flesh the law
> with its commands and regulations.** His purpose was to create in
> himself one new humanity out of the two, thus making peace,

Jesus is foretelling "The Desolation of Jerusalem" by the Roman armies and is directed to his followers as well as to the Jewish people that still kept observance of the Law. The first fulfillment occurred in 66C.E. when the Roman armies assaulted Jerusalem and its temple, a second assault was made in 70 C.E. which resulted in the destruction of Jerusalem and the temple.

The parallel account in Luke reads as follows.

Luke 21:20-24   New English Translation

> 20 “But when you see Jerusalem surrounded by armies, then know that
> its desolationhas come near. 21 Then those who are in Judea must flee
> to the mountains. Those  who are inside the city must depart. Those
> who are out in the country must not enter it, 22 because these are
> days of vengeance, to fulfill all that is written. 23 Woe to those who
> are pregnant and to those who are nursing their babies in those days!
> For there will be great distress  on the earth and wrath against this
> people. 24 They will fall by the edge of the sword and be led away as
> captives among all nations. Jerusalem will be trampled down by the
> Gentiles until the times of the Gentiles are fulfilled.

Conclusion.

> 20 Pray that your flight will not occur in the winter or on the
> Sabbath.

The vast majority of Jews ignored Jesus warnings, his disciples heeded the warning in 66 C.E. and as a result, were saved from the horrors of the siege of 70 C.E. Christians fled  to the city of Pella in the foothills to the north.

**Winter.**

The fact that they were asked to pray that this did not occur in winter was that weather conditions, such as cold, heavy rains,  and flooding would make it difficult to travel, find shelter, or food

**Sabbath**

Restriction t due to the Sabbath Law would make it difficult to travel great distances, and also the city gates remained closed on the Sabbath.(Acts 1:12)

From Wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pella,_Jordan

First Christians: the "flight to Pella"

In what is known as the "flight to Pella", around the time of the Roman siege and destruction of Jerusalem in 70 CE, tradition holds that a Jewish sect of Nazarenes made their way to Pella and settled in the city which became a Jewish Christian hub during the early days of Christianity.[10] According to Epiphanius, the disciples had been miraculously told by Christ to abandon Jerusalem because of the siege it was about to undergo.[11]